# index.html is appearing blank in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have downloaded everything, all dependencies and npm, node and angular-cli by showing one of the block from google only.

https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/03/25/getting-started-with-angular-2-step-by-step-1-your-first-component/

I have created a new project with the following Command

```
       ng new MyFirstApp --style scss
```

Project has been created successfully but I am trying to run the application,
I am getting blank page with fevicon icon. It is like my page is getting reloeded but when I am trying to show my "Template things" from app.componant.ts through template decorator in app-root div, it is not showing.

below is my HTML file:

`Index.html`

```
          <!doctype html>
         <html lang="en">
           <head>
             <meta charset="utf-8">
             <title>ShoppingApp</title>
             <base href="/">

            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-    
            scale=1">
             <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">  
          </head>

          <body>
             <app-root></app-root>
          </body> 
          </html>
```

`app.component.ts`

```
       import { Component } from '@angular/core';

       @Component({
            selector: 'app-root',
            templateUrl: '<h1>App Works</h1>'
          })
          export class AppComponent {
            // constructor({});
          }
```

My whole project folder is created by angular-cli only.

Comment: Have you checked the web console of your browser for error messages that might help explain what's going on?

Comment: try create angular project using ' ng new MyFirstApp --style=scss ' and ng set defaults.styleExt scss

Comment: #kshetline Thank You for the reply.
Yes I have checked console, it is not showing any error.
webpack : compiltion is getting succeded.

Comment: What about the browser's development console? Usually accessed via [F12]. Does that show errors?

Comment: Hi Roddy,
Yes It is showing  SCRIPT5022"Exception thrown and not caught"

Comment: My Question is, Do I need to include script reference in index.html page ?

Comment: Thank You guys for the reply,
But I got solution. I just needed to uncomments the lines from src/polifills.js, and it works

Comment: used npm install ? thats first thing to do and then npm serve --open

Comment: Yes I have used that. Actually problem was with that uncommented lines as  I mentioned above